# Not less than enough and not more Expression or Idiom

Tags: idioms, expressions, idiom-request

I'm looking for an expression or idiom in English that expresses this context:

> Anything that you overdo or it exceeds its limit is annoying and unacceptable. And also the same thing goes for anything that you do less than needed. Always try to stick with the middle. Not more and not less.

Comment: Close,, but not exactly the context you specify: "Not a penny more, not a penny less"

Comment: This idea could be described in many ways,  for example "just right".  I'm not quite sure what you want here!  The quoted text is good English and it expresses itself well.  What else do you want? What do you want to say?